# Gravar arquivo .txt node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Preciso gerar um arquivo txt com algumas informações e salvá-lo no C: Como posso fazer isso utilizando o node.js?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usando a API *filesystem* do NodeJS.

A API tem um monte de detalhes e te dá infinitas possibilidade, dê uma lida na [documentação](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_file_system) para maiores detalhes.

Lembre-se de que é necessário ter permissão para escrever na pasta.

Um exemplo bem simples.

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.writeFile("C:\\Pasta\\meuarquivo.txt", "Hello, txt!", function(erro) {

    if(erro) {
        throw erro;
    }

    console.log("Arquivo salvo");
});
```